# Spin button values and rename sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to create a new sheet with a value change in the spin button. If the ActiveSheet is 2021 Aug then the new sheet should be 2021 Sep. "AA3" and "AG3" are connected to the spin button values. I want to have the new sheet name as spin button values or "AA3" + "AG3" values.

In short,

1. for the new sheet, one month increment in spin button
2. change **sheet name** as per spin button values or text box values or "AA3" + "AG3" values
   Preferably, showing as Aug-2021,  Sep-2021 and so on...

[image: mySheet]

This so far I have coded with help from Stackoverflow and various webpage. It creates a new sheet but doesn't change the value and also the sheet name.

```
Sub CreateSheet()

    ActiveSheet.Select
    Sheets(Sheets.Count).Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    
    If ActiveSheet.SpinButton2.Value <= 10 Then 
        ActiveSheet.SpinButton2.Value = SpinButton2.Value + 1
    ElseIf ActiveSheet.SpinButton2.Value = 11 Then
        ActiveSheet.SpinButton1.Value = ActiveSheet.SpinButton1.Value + 1 And ActiveSheet.SpinButton2.Value = 0
    End If

    ActiveSheet.name = SpinButton2.Value & SpinButton1.Value
    
End Sub

Private Sub SpinButton1_Change()

    SpinButton1.Max = 2999
    SpinButton1.Min = 1900
    SpinButton1.SmallChange = 1
    TextBox1.Value = SpinButton1.Value
        
    Call MakeDate(SpinButton1.Value, SpinButton2.Value)


Private Sub SpinButton2_Change()
    Dim Mths As Variant

    SpinButton2.Max = 11
    SpinButton2.Min = 0
    Mths = Array("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "June", "July", "Aug", "Sept", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec")
    TextBox2.Text = Mths(SpinButton2.Value)
        
    Call MakeDate(SpinButton1.Value, SpinButton2.Value)
        
End Sub

Private Sub MakeDate(sp1Val As String, sp2Val As String)
    Dim tempDate As Date

    tempDate = DateValue(sp1Val & "-" & sp2Val + 1 & "-" & 1)

    With Range("AE3")
        .NumberFormat = "yyyy"
        .Value = tempDate
    End With
     
    With Range("AA3")
         .NumberFormat = "mmm"
         .Value = tempDate
    End With

End Sub
```

**Update 1**

From @vinod answer, I changed like this and it creates only one sheet and correct name from Feb-2021 until Dec-2021

```
NewName = ActiveSheet.TextBox2.Text & "-" & ActiveSheet.TextBox1.Value ActiveSheet.Name = NewName
```

The problem now is when copy Dec-2021 sheet it creates duplicate Dec-2021 and spinbuttle.value is not changed.

[image: Error]

```
  Sub CreateSheet()
    
    ' Display a messagebox based on the response

CarryOn = MsgBox("Do you want to create a new sheet? ", vbYesNo, "Continue?")
  
If CarryOn = vbYes Then
  
    ActiveSheet.Select
    Sheets(Sheets.Count).Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    
    
If ActiveSheet.SpinButton2.Value <= 10 Then ActiveSheet.SpinButton2.Value = ActiveSheet.SpinButton2.Value + 1
ElseIf ActiveSheet.SpinButton2.Value = 11 Then
    ActiveSheet.SpinButton2.Value = ActiveSheet.SpinButton2.Value - 11 And ActiveSheet.SpinButton1.Value = ActiveSheet.SpinButton1.Value + 1
End If

NewName = ActiveSheet.TextBox2.Text & "-" & ActiveSheet.TextBox1.Value
ActiveSheet.Name = NewName
       
End Sub
```

Comment: I have changed like this and it worked. `code` NewName = ActiveSheet.TextBox2.Text & "-" & ActiveSheet.TextBox1.Value
ActiveSheet.Name = NewName

Comment: Please, revert the last edit. After receiving an answer, you can not (should not) change the question. It may invalidate the existing answer(s) and is therefore not allowed. If you have a new question, ask a new question, and refer to this one if it helps to clarify. Also, for review requests there is a separate SO site "Code Review". But please read their directions on what to post there.

Comment: If the answer is incorrect in some way, please comment **under the answer** and defer from ticking the checkmark until the answer is corrected. When evaluating an answer, you should of course take in consideration what you asked. Still, you are free to accept or un-accept answers as you see fit. Further information regarding [asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) is on the [help] pages.

Comment: Ok, I tried my best to revert the post. @Tom Brunberg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I managed to fix the problem.

[image: It worked!]

```
Sub CreateSheet()

   
    ' Display a messagebox based on the response

    CarryOn = MsgBox("Do you want to create a new sheet? ", vbYesNo, "Continue?")
  
    If CarryOn = vbYes Then
        Sheets(Sheets.Count).Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    End If
    
    
    If ActiveSheet.SpinButton2.Value <= 10 Then
        ActiveSheet.SpinButton2.Value = ActiveSheet.SpinButton2.Value + 1
    Else
        ActiveSheet.SpinButton2.Value = ActiveSheet.SpinButton2.Value - 11
        ActiveSheet.SpinButton1.Value = ActiveSheet.SpinButton1.Value + 1
    End If

    NewName = ActiveSheet.TextBox2.Text & "-" & ActiveSheet.TextBox1.Value
    ActiveSheet.Name = NewName   
       
End Sub
```

Comment: Glad you got it working for you, but a little puzzled. Do you really want to copy everything on the old sheet to the new one?

Comment: @ Tom Brunbergyes Yes It is ok to copy everything. I am making a simple scheduler and I have a macro to delete what I don't need.

Comment: @DEEK when you say you want NEW sheet you get help to create a new sheet.  And if you intend to have a copy of the existing sheet, renames as something else, then its a whole different scenario.  Anyway, glad it worked out well for you.  Cheers !!

Answer (score 1):

As per the flow of logic for your task you need to add the following in the code where you want to add new sheet.

```
NewName = ActiveSheet.Range("AA3").Value & "-" & ActiveSheet.Range("AG3").Value
Sheets.Add.Name = NewName
```

You can place this code anywhere you want, on a button click, or on spin button click, or any trigger you choose.

Comment: If it satisfies your requirement, pls mark the answer ....  so those of us searching to help others will have a truncated list.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked to change sheet name but some reason it creates 2 sheets one is correct the other one is copied from original sheet. @Vinod

Comment: ~  Sub CreateSheet()

CarryOn = MsgBox("Do you want to create a new sheet? ", vbYesNo, "Continue?")


  
If CarryOn = vbYes Then
  
    ActiveSheet.Select
    Sheets(Sheets.Count).Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
        
If ActiveSheet.SpinButton2.Value <= 10 Then ActiveSheet.SpinButton2.Value = ActiveSheet.SpinButton2.Value + 1
    ElseIf ActiveSheet.SpinButton2.Value = 11 Then
    ActiveSheet.SpinButton2.Value = ActiveSheet.SpinButton2.Value - 11 ' and ActiveSheet.SpinButton1.Value = ActiveSheet.SpinButton1.Value + 1 And
 End If

Comment: I am not sure how to show the code properly in the comment above. It is working well un til spin button 2021 Dec and then it creates same 2021 Dec sheet. After that If I creates a new sheet it crashes with 400 error.

Comment: @DEEK From where are you calling `CreateSheet()`? In the comment above in `CreateSheet()` you call `ActiveSheet.Select Sheets(Sheets.Count).Copy` which makes a copy of the last sheet of current sheets. That creates one new sheet. What in your code creates the second one? There is no other statement that would create a second sheet. Have you stepped (with F8) through the code execution?

Comment: @Tom Brunberg I have modified the answer from Vinod and it creates one sheet. I think '''Sheets.Add.Name = NewName''' was the problem. but I have a new problem. Detailed info in the ''Update 1'' in my post. Thank you

Comment: @Tom Brunberg I think the problem was **Sheets.Add.Name = NewName** It creates a new sheet with the correct name but has not copied anything in cells(blank). **ActiveSheet.Select Sheets(Sheets.Count).Copy** this one copy the last one but not correct name. for the spin button my IF coding was wrong. I kept trying and trying and worked. Thank you!